# Copying blocks - copying captured variables of primitive types

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've searched several topics about copying blocks, but I couldn't have found information that I'm interested in.

When we define a block, we have an opportunity to capture variables from its enclosing scope. Since blocks are stored on the stack, and variables are captured by *value*, everything is clear here:

- in case of primitive types, we acquire additional variable (localized also on the stack), e.g. some *const int*, that has identical value as the original *int* variable
- in case of pointers, we acquire a copy of specific pointer - so that reference count for pointed object is increased by 1.

Now, I don't know what happens when we move (copy) a block from the stack to the heap. For captured pointers it is simple - we acquire a copy of those pointers. But what happens with captured variables of primitive types? Variables on the heap are allocated dynamically, so we can refer to the them only with pointers. It means that we cannot simply copy the e.g. *int* variable to the heap - we can dynamically allocate an *int* variable, assign it to some *int ** pointer, and through that pointer write the appropriate value - the same as in the original *int* variable. But for this we would need some additional mechanism, that woks behind the scenes. Additionally, when we capture some variable in the block, block "prepares" itself to operate on a variable of specific size and in specific manner - if we would change the variable of primitive type to a pointer, it usually would have different size and it would require different way of handling it...

So could someone please tell me, how does it work in depth? Or am I simply wrong at some point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the gory details in the [Block Implementation Specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html).

It is easiest to explain with an example.  Consider this simple function containing a simple block:

```
void outerFunction() {
    int x = 7;
    dispatch_block_t block = ^{
        printf("%d\n", x);
    };
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

Remember that `dispatch_block_t` is a typedef for `void (^)(void)`.

To compile that code, the compiler will first create two structure definitions:

```
struct Block_descriptor_1 {
    unsigned long reserved;
    unsigned long size;
    const char *signature;
};

struct Block_literal_1 {
    void *isa;
    int flags;
    int reserved;
    void (*invoke)(void *);
    struct Block_descriptor_1 *descriptor;
    int x;
};
```

Then it creates a global variable of type `Block_descriptor_1`, which contains the size of `Block_literal_1` and an encoding of the type signature of the block:

```
struct Block_descriptor_1 block_descriptor_1 = {
    .size = sizeof(struct Block_literal_1),
    .signature = "v4@?0"
};
```

And it creates a function containing the body of the block:

```
void outerFunction_block_invoke(void *voidLiteral) {
    struct Block_literal_1 *literal = (struct Block_literal_1 *)voidLiteral;
    printf("%d\n", literal->x);
}
```

Notice that the body of the block has been rewritten so that the access to the variable `x` from the enclosing scope is now an access to a member of the block literal.

Finally, the compiler rewrites the original function to create a block literal on the stack and to use the address of that block literal instead of the block:

```
void outerFunction2() {
    int x = 7;
    struct Block_literal_1 block_literal_1 = {
        .isa = __NSConcreteStackBlock,
        .flags  = BLOCK_HAS_SIGNATURE,
        .invoke = outerFunction_block_invoke,
        .descriptor = &block_descriptor_1,
        .x = x
    };
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        (__bridge dispatch_block_t)&block_literal_1);
}
```

Notice that the block literal starts with a pointer to a special Objective-C `Class`.  This allows the block literal to be treated as an Objective-C object.

If you add the `__block` attribute to the local variable `x`, it gets more complicated.  In that case, the compiler has to create another structure to hold that variable along with information about the variable (like how to retain and release it if the variable is a pointer to an object).  This is all explained in the specification I linked at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation with a nice example :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but perhaps a simple explanation of how blocks actually work will clarify things.

A block is effectively an instance of an anonymous class. The class has an ivar for every captured variable. When the block is instantiated, all the captured variables are copied into their respective ivars on the block, which is stored on the stack at the moment.

When the block is copied to the heap, it creates a new block object on the heap, and copies all the ivars from the stack block to the heap block (it also retains any captured obj-c objects at this point). There's no confusion over pointers to primitive values and whatnot; there's just one malloc'd area on the heap that contains all the captured values, just like any other obj-c object.

Meanwhile the actual code in the block simply accesses the captured variables by using the equivalent of `implicit_block_pointer->backing_ivar`, exactly the same way a method on an object will access ivars of the object.

Comment: A block is not an anonymous class - all blocks are instances of the class `__NSGlobalBlock__` (when copied off of the stack), with a different backing function pointer & trampoline. I would expect you of all people to get that right.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Not literally, no. That's why I said "effectively". It's a simple way to think about it.

Comment: but it isn't, in fact, it becomes more complex when you look at it as an anonymous class. If you look at it as an anonymous class, the lines get blurred between a protocol and a block (can my block implement a protocol if it's an anonymous class?), where the two are most certainly not equivalent.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: What do protocols have to do with anything? You can't even declare methods on the block, let alone implement a protocol. The idea of using an anonymous class as a simple explanation works because people already are (or at least should be) familiar with how an instance of a class contains and accesses ivars. Blocks contain and access captured variables in a very similar fashion, even if it's not actually using the obj-c class implementation to do so.

Comment: That's my point - if you think that they're anonymous classes, then you start wondering if they act like a traditional class, which they don't. It was a bad analogy to make to begin with, considering many APIs support both blocks & delegate based callbacks.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I still don't understand your objection. Instances never "act like a traditional class", because they're not classes. They're instances. Really the only thing that breaks this abstraction is if you call `-class` on multiple blocks and log the results, but you're not supposed to care about the class that a particular block is an instance of anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is missing a level of pointers, if only you'd learn to program using Algol-68... (`ref loc` anybody?)

*[The following is somewhat simplified to present the gist of what is going on.]*

When you declare a variable, say:

```
int x;
```

You are instructing the compiler to find a location capable of storing the representation of an `int` and to use that location for values you refer to using the name `x`.

Skipping the "find" bit, the compiler constructs an internal table ,the *symbol table*, which maps names, `x` here, to locations - and locations are represented either as absolute addresses (aka pointers) or as offsets from *something*, e.g. as something like "the 7th location on the stack". The *something* is sometimes stored inside the computer in a special named location called a *register*, e.g. there is a register where the stack pointer is stored and so variables stored as offsets to the stack pointer are located as offsets from the value stored in this register.

Using this table the compiler seeing `x` can determine the address of where the representation of `x`'s value is stored.

At the machine instruction level reading or writing a variable involves using an instruction which takes an address. So by the time you get down to the actual machine code all variables are referenced via pointers.

Now to your block case. When you capture our example `x` integer variable the compiler allocates a location for it within a structure describing the block. In the symbol table it creates an entry for `x` and maps it so something like "the 6th location in the *block variable area*". The location of the *block variable area* is arranged to be in a specific location, maybe a register just as with the stack pointer above, and then the machine instructions find the value of `x` as an offset from that location.

When the block is stack-based the block variable area will be on the stack, when it is heap-based it will be in the heap, but as its location is stored in a register before the block is executed the code of the block never needs to change - `x` is always at the same offset relative to the block variable area.

Hopefully all that makes sense!

Comment: It actually makes a lot of sense - thanks for this explanation how addressing works :-)

Answer (score 1):

The additional mechanism that 'works behind the scenes' is just C struct member access. Whether on the stack of heap, blocks are structs with members for each captured variable (they're in fact Objective-C objects, also). When the block is executed, a function is called that takes a pointer to the block as an argument. This function accesses the captured variables like `blockPointer->capturedVar1`. It doesn't matter where `blockPointer` points to at this point - all that matter is there's space allocated for the captured variable within a struct somewhere.

You may find this to be enlightening: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html

Comment: How does UIView's + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations access an N number of UIView objects??

Comment: @ThiagoPeres Not sure what you mean could you clarify?